# ¿Cómo incluir un bloque markdown con strapdown.js y ejecutar un javascript incrustado?

Tags: html, embebido, markdown

El problema está en qué el markdown lo lee perfectamente hasta que intento (dentro de él) ejecutar un script js. Alguien me puede decir que está fallando?

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Pruebas MD con JS</title>
</head>
<body>

<xmp theme="United">

# h1
##### h5
---

#### h4

```javascript
Array.prototype.sumar = function() {
    return this.reduce((a, b) => a * b);
};

const vector = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const resultado = vector.sumar();
```

    
> RESULTADO: 55.

<script type="application/javascript">

    Array.prototype.sumar = function() {
        return this.reduce((a, b) => a * b);
    };

    const vector = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    const resultado = vector.sumar();
    
    document.write(resultado);
    
</script>
    
#### h4

```javascript
Array.prototype.maximo = function() {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, this);
};

const vector = [50, 10, 70, 0, 20, 40];
const resultado = vector.maximo();
```

> RESULTADO: 70.
    
</xmp>

<script src="http://strapdownjs.com/v/0.2/strapdown.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
````

Comment: Quizás esto te pueda ayudar: http://strapdownjs.com/

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Me funciona, pero cuando cierro el tag xmp para incluir un script js o dentro no lo ejecuta.

Comment: No conozco mucho de esa librería. Fue la primera que encontré al hacer una búsqueda en google luego de leer tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola @dddenis. Stackoverflow en español no es un sustituto de Google, por lo que deberías incluir un ejemplo sencillo, completo y reproducible de lo que estás haciendo, porque de otra manera, solo estaríamos adivinando.

Comment: Tienes razón @toledano, ya he editado la pregunta, disculpa las molestias.

Comment: En tu ejemplo no hay ninguna librería de javascript que convierta el markdown.

Comment: Ya le agregué, pero aún así nada.

Comment: El ejemplo si funciona, @dddnenis. No veo ningún problema por aquí.

Comment: Una pregunta?? donde añades este código? osea yo cree una carpeta docs dentro de Scripts y no se si es ahi donde debo escribir el código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es algo complicado de encontrar. Resulta que la etiqueta [`<xmp>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp) es obsoleta desde HTML 3.2 y peor aún, no ha sido implementada por los navegadores de manera consistente. Por otro lado strapdown.js sólo implementa el plugin usando un `<textarea>` o un `<xmp>` y en ninguno de los dos se puede usar javascript dentro del contenido.

La solución sería poner tu código afuera y usar un html con id para saber donde vas a insertar el texto ya que el plugin deja las etiquetas html sin modificar

```js
window.onload = function() {
  Array.prototype.sumar = function() {
    return this.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  };
  
  Array.prototype.maximo = function() {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, this);
  };
  
  function sumar() {
    const vector = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    const resultado = vector.sumar();

    document.getElementById('sumar').innerHTML = resultado;
  }
  
  function maximo() {
    const vector = [50, 10, 70, 0, 20, 40];
    const resultado = vector.maximo();
    document.getElementById('maximo').innerHTML = resultado;
  }
  
  sumar();
  maximo();
};
```

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Pruebas MD con JS</title>
</head>
<body>

<xmp theme="United">

# h1
##### h5
---

#### h4

```javascript
Array.prototype.sumar = function() {
    return this.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
};

const vector = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const resultado = vector.sumar();
```

    
> RESULTADO: <span id="sumar"></span>.
   
#### h4

```javascript
Array.prototype.maximo = function() {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, this);
};

const vector = [50, 10, 70, 0, 20, 40];
const resultado = vector.maximo();
```

> RESULTADO: <span id="maximo"></span>.
    
</xmp>

<script src="http://strapdownjs.com/v/0.2/strapdown.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
````

Puedes leer más sobre el problema en este [issue](https://github.com/arturadib/strapdown/issues/40) de github.

Como nota personal tengo que decirte que extender el prototipo de los objetos nativos de javascript por lo general es una mala práctica, lee esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice) de stackoverflow en ingés para que entiendas porqué.